# Validating a large dictionary of set strings with user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I have a profile form that has a lot of user selections and I am sort of stumped on a good approach to validate what the user enters, when passing validation mapping those values to object properties.

For example I have a dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> objProfileSelections = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static string MySelections(string key)
{
    objProfileSelections.Add("1", "No Answer");
    objProfileSelections.Add("3", "Less Than $25,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("5", "$35,000 to $50,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("7", "$50,000 to $75,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("9", "$75,000 to $100,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("11", "$100,000 to $150,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("13", "$150,000+");
    objProfileSelections.Add("2", "No Answer");
    objProfileSelections.Add("4", "Less Than $25,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("6", "$35,000 to $50,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("8", "$50,000 to $75,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("10", "$75,000 to $100,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("12", "$100,000 to $150,000");
    objProfileSelections.Add("14", "$150,000+");
    string item;
    objProfileSelections.TryGetValue(key, out item);
    return item;
}
```

Id like to pass in a list of key strings from the user and pass those items to populate an object. The issue is I don't know how to code it so it know which property to go to, I looked at reflection, but I couldn't find any examples that have a set dictionary of values that map to property names.

To make a bit more clear, when a user makes a selection it passes as a parameter in the dictionary, and the dictionary outputs the items. From key 1 comes value No Answer. If the user selected all the check boxes it would be value  - (1,3,5,7,9,11,13). I need to extract those values when there is a matching key to a matching property. For example if the user clicks 1,5 but leaves the rest unchecked, how do I know which selections the user made? How do I get the program to know which property to populate based on the results?

*edit
some properties I would like it mapped to

```
public string MyAnnualIncome{ get; set; }
public List<string> InterestAnnualIncome{ get; set; }
```

So the first property would be taking one value, and the second property would be taking multiple values.

When a key matches a value comes out the dictionary, I would need the odd values going to MyAnnualIncome and the even values going to InterestAnnualIncome.

---

- so no one is confused odd and even keys are set up for a purpose, odd numbers belonging to a certain group of properties and the even ones belonging to another based on the html selections (even being my selections, odd being what I am interested in)

---

*Update
Is there a way I can possibly use the keys like 1,3,5 and pass that into a list using the except extension method. Then take the results and use a method to convert the values from enumerated data types to strings?

Comment: Clearly, someone understood the question, because you got an upvote.  But I truly don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let me try to be a bit more clear, The dictionary above is set up as a static dictionary to validate user selections. The html form has a checkbox list with those values (1,2,3,4,5,6 etc etc). So when the user clicks no answer,Less Than $25,000, $35,000 to $50,000, he chose values 1,3,5. If the user decides to tamper with the form and inputs (Z238) it will return null. But if the user does everything correctly I feel like the proper thing to do is to map it to a user property called List<string> Annual Income.

Comment: That helps, thank you.  Can you expand the code in your post to include these properties you want to map to?  There is no information on what these are, where they are defined, how you want them returned.  You can even post some invalid code if it helps to illustrate what you are hoping to accomplish.

Comment: Do you want to convert a key to a c# property name ? Once you got the property do you want to set it ?  What is the type of the properties  (bool, string, enum, ...) ? What are the values to be assigned to the properties ? May we assume that you receive or build from checkbox values a list of keys ?

Comment: Just strings, the profile would be things like a dating website would have. Properties like hair color, income, and occupation. For other datatypes I handle that separately. The large amount of strings I have I am just confused on how I populate the User Profile object with values extracted by the keys.

Comment: Why don't you include in the key the propertyname, e.g. "56:Hair", "63:color" ?

Comment: I am sorry I don't get it, Hair has different types(wavy curley straight / brunette, blonde). I don't see how that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understood your question. 
I would add a small helper class (this is a solution which doesn't use reflection, but uses delegates instead):

```
public class PropertyModifier
{
   private string text;
   private Func<string> modifier;

   public PropertyModifier(Func<string> modifier)
   {
       this.modifier = modifier;
   }

   public PropertyModifier With(string text)
   {
       PropertyModifier newModifier = new PropertyModifier(modifier);
       newModifier.text = text;
       return newModifier;
   }

   public void Modify()
   {
       modifier(Text);
   }
}
```

Then I would rewrite your code and have the dictionary map to this class instead to string:

```
public static Dictionary<string, PropertyModifier> objProfileSelections = new Dictionary<string, PropertyModifier>();

public static MyUserProfile Profile; //Assuming this is the object you want to modify

public static string MySelections(string key)
{
    PropertyModifier myIncome = new PropertyModifier(text => Profile.MyAnnualIncome = text);
    PropertyModifier interestIncome = new PropertyModifier(text => Profile.InterestAnnualIncome.Add(text)); 

    objProfileSelections.Add("1", myIncome.With("No Answer"));
    objProfileSelections.Add("3", myIncome.With("Less Than $25,000"));
    ...
    objProfileSelections.Add("2", interestIncome.With("No Answer"));
    objProfileSelections.Add("4", interestIncome.With("Less Than $25,000"));
    ...
}
```

Then, when processing the user's selection, get the mapped PropertyModifier from the dictionary and call its `Modify` method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this code to illustrate how you can modify the properties of the different classes that may compose a profile. Modifications are done by reflection only, i.e. just providing the class name, the property name that will vary in each class and the string value to be assigned to the property.

*Not sure that it fits your expectations :(*

```
Profile profile = new Profile() ;
profile.SetPropertyValue("hair","color","brown") ;        

internal class Profile()
{
  private Hair hair_ = new Hair();   
  private Job  job_  = new Job ();

  internal Hair hair { get { return hair_ ; } } 
  internal Job  job  { get { return job_  ; } } 

  private void SetPropertyValue(string profileItemName, string ItemPropertyName, string value)
  { // it is assumed that the different items (hair or job) of the Profile are accessible 
    // with a a property

    // first find the Item object, i.e. hair or job                  
    object itemObj = this.GetType().GetProperty(profileItemName).GetValue(this,null);
    // assign to Item property the input value, e.g. hair.color=Brown
    itemObj.GetType().GetProperty(ItemPropertyName).SetValue(itemObj, value, null);
   }
 }

internal class Hair()
{
  private string color_ ;   
  private string style_ ;

  internal string   color { get { return color_  ; } set {color_ = value ; } } 
  internal string   style { get { return style_  ; } set {style_ = value ; } } 
 }
```

Comment: My expectations? Dude you took the time out of your day to help me that alone is awesome. Just going to get some brain food before I check that out, thanks a lot man!